# How can I run through a Perl program step by step?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a Perl program written by someone else. When I run it, it silently exits without writing anything to the logfile. Is there a way I can run this Perl program step by step, line by line by the interpreter and thus get to see where it terminates?

Comment: `perldoc `[`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is the Perl debugger which you can invoke with `perl -d`.

Documentation can be found in [perldoc perldebug](http://p3rl.org/perldebug) and [perldoc perldebtut](http://p3rl.org/perldebtut).

Probably the most useful commands would be:

```
s                 - step into current line.
n                 - step over current line.
r                 - step out of current function.
p <expr>          - print the expression.
b <line|subnm>    - sets a breakpoint
T                 - produce a stack trace.
c [<line|subnm>]  - continue running with optional one-time breakpoint.
h                 - help (for other commands).
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd like to add that the 'q' command is used to exit the debugger :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Perl module called "ptkdb" which is a standalone Perl  interactive debugger. It works using the [Tcl/Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) GUI, so you'll need that, too.

Depending on your OS you'll need to [add some required modules](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/).

Invoke it using

```
perl -d:ptkdb <your script>
```

If running some Unix/Linux system, you also need an X server.

Answer (score 3):

Hachi has the answer. Use the Perl debugger by running `perl` with the `-d` flag. For information on how to use the debugger past starting it, see the [Perl Debugging Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. The first is the one which Hachi and llioin already gave which is using the command-line switch "-d".

Or use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). I am tried and used [Komodo IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_IDE) which works like charm.